# How to model errors around the estimation of proportions - with measurement error?

Tags: estimation, binomial-distribution, beta-distribution, measurement-error

I have a situation I'm trying to model. I would appreciate any ideas on how to model this, or if there are known names for such a situation.

**Background:**

Let's assume we have a large number of movies (M). For each movie, I'd like to know the proportion of people in the population who enjoy watching these movies. So for movie $m_1$ we'd say that $p_1$ proportion of the population would say "yes" to "did you enjoy watching this movie?" question. And the same for movie $m_j$, we'd have proportion $p_j$ (up to movie $m_M$).

We sample $n$ people, and ask each of them to say if they enjoyed watching movies $m_1, m_2, ..., m_M$ of the movies. We can now easily build estimations for $p_1, ..., p_M$ using standard point estimates, and build confidence intervals for these estimations using the standard methods ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval)).

But there is a problem.

**Problem: measurement error**

Some of the people in the sample do not bother to answer truthfully. They instead just answer yes/no to the question regardless of their true preference. Luckily, for some sample of the M movies, we know the true proportion of people who like the movies. So let's assume that M is very large, but that for the first 100 movies (of some indexing) we know the real proportion.
So we know the real values of $p_1, p_2, ..., p_{100}$, and we have their estimations $\hat p_1 , \hat p_2, ..., \hat p_{100}$. While we still want to know the confidence intervals that takes this measurement error into account for $p_{101} , p_{102}, ..., p_M$, using our estimators $\hat p_{101} , \hat p_{102}, ..., \hat p_M$.

I could imagine some simple model such as:

$$\hat p_i \sim N(p_i, \epsilon^2 + \eta^2 )$$

Where $\eta^2$ is for the measurement error.

**Questions**:

1. Are there other reasonable models for this type of situation?
2. What are good ways to estimate $\eta^2$ (for the purpose of building confidence interval)? For example, would using $\hat \eta^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum (p_i - \hat p_i)^2$ make sense? Or, for example, it makes sense to first take some transformation of the $p_i$ and $\hat p_i$ values (using logit, probit or some other transformation from the 0 to 1, to an -inf to inf scale)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a simple enough Bayesian solution here.
I haven't tried to implement any of this though!

Without measurement error, this is a simple Beta-Bernoulli model:

$$
\begin{align}
p_i     &\sim \text{Beta}(\alpha_i, \beta_i)\\
y_{i,j} &\sim \text{Bernoulli}(p_i)
\end{align}
$$

where $p_i$ is the proportion of people who like movie $i$,
and $y_{i,j} = 1$ if person $j$ reported liking movie $i$ and $0$ otherwise.
$\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are prior parameters, and can be used to encode information about the proportion of people we would expect to like each movie ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) for details on the Beta distribution).

If there is an unknown probability that each person just responds at random for every movie, we can add an additional set of parameters, $r_j$ ($r$ for *random*) encoding the probability that person $j$ is a random responder,
and use Beta priors for each person.
I assume that random responders have a 50% chance of responding that they liked the movie.

$$
\begin{align}
p_i     &\sim \text{Beta}(\alpha_i, \beta_i) \\
r_j     &\sim \text{Beta}(a_r, b_r) \\
y_{i,j} &\sim \text{Bernoulli}( r_j \times 0.5 + (1-r_j)\times(p_i));
\end{align}
$$

On its own, this model probably isn't identifiable,
but fortunately you have a lot of prior information about the first 100 movies. This means you can set strong priors on $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ for $i$ in $1, 2, \dots, 100$, and use non-informative priors (e.g. $\alpha_i = \beta_i = 1$) for the rest of the movies. This information should constrain things enough to have some idea who the random responders are, and to down-weight their responses for the rest of the movies.

This kind of model can be fairly easily fit using standard Bayesian tools like Stan, PyMC3, or JAGS.